# Power sets as a function

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the correspondence \begin{align*}f: \mathcal{P}(X)&\to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))\\A&\mapsto \mathcal{P}(A)\end{align*} a function?

---

If it is, I am thinking of using it to solve this problem

> Let $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of subsets of a set $X$. Are the relations:
>   $$\mathcal{P}\big(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\big) = \bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{P}(A_i)\\\mathcal{P}\big(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\big) = \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal{P}(A_i)$$ true?

If $f$ is a function, then the answer is quick and easy (it would need to be injective for the first relation to be true, and it seems it would be).

Comment: It's possible that set theorists will take some issue with your definition of function, but I'd say you're already looking at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a function. I don't see how it is useful for solving your problem. If I were faced with those questions, instead of trying to find some way to state them in **more** arcane and confusing language, I'd be trying to state them more simply and clearly. In plain language, the questions are:

> Is it true that something is a subset of the intersection of a bunch of sets if and only if it's a subset of each of them?
>   
>   Is it true that a set is a subset of the union of a bunch of sets if and only if it's a subset of one of them?

Offhand I'd guess that one and a half of those statements are true.

**P.S.** Although $\mathcal P$ is a function, your idea for answering the questions is wrong. First let me explain your notational confusion.

Consider a function $f:X\to Y.$ If $a$ is an **element** of $X,$ the symbol $f(a)$ denotes (as usual) the value of the function at $a,$ and is an **element** of $Y.$ On the other hand, if $A$ is a **subset** of $X,$ then $f[A]$ (note the square brackets) denotes the set $\{f(a):a\in A\}$ and is a **subset** of $Y.$

We often ignore this distinction and use round brackets $f(\cdot)$ in both cases, and usually this does no harm. However, it gets confusing if the elements of $X$ are themselves sets, as they are here. In particular, the identity $f[A\cup B]=f[A]\cup f[B]$ (note square brackets) is always true, but $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$ is usually false.

Comment: I agree with a simple and straightforward approach is best. But just to clarify what I was trying to do, I wanted to use $\mathcal{P}\big(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\big) = f\big(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\big)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_i) = \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal{P}(A_i)$ which works for any function $f$. For the intersection, we get an inclusion, and equality if $f$ is injective.

Comment: Oh my. You have managed to confuse yourself with fancy notation. To start with, the statement about unions is ***FALSE***.For example, suppose $I=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5$ be disjoint one-element sets. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is a $5$-element set, so $\mathcal P(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)$ had $32$ elements; but $\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal P(A_i)$ has only $6$ elements.

Comment: The common notation $$f(A)=\{f(a):a\in A\}$$ can lead to confusion because $f(\cdot)$ is used to mean two different things. Using a more precise notation such as $$f[A]=\{f(a):a\in A\}$$ it would be easier to explain what you're doing wrong: $$f[A\cup B]=f[A]\cup f[B]$$ is true always, but $$f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$$ hardly ever.

Comment: @bof: While not an established notation, I think that something like $f^\in(A)$ would be a clearer notation: We a re looking at a *different* function that is determined by the original; the function $f:X\to Y$ gives rise to the function $f^\in:\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y), A\mapsto\{f(x):x\in A\}$.

Comment: @bof you are right, I did confuse myself. Can you clarify one thing: using your notations, for a set $A$, I understand $f[A]$, but what does $f(A)$ mean?

Comment: @celtschk thanks for your comment, it definitely helped understand what I did wrong.

Comment: In any case, I understand now how my approach was wrong. Even considering a function like $f^{\in}$ wouldn't help solve my problem. I'll just go at it the simple way. Thanks

Comment: If the domain of the function $f$ is a set of sets, and the set $A$ is an element of that domain, then naturally $f(A)$ is just the value of $f$ at $A.$ For example, $f(A)$ might be the power set of $A.$